# How to create a popup that provides user multiples options?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, user-interface

Currently I am designing a user opinion page where I planned to get input from user like **"Is it suitable?"**

Possibly the input could be **YES / NO / No Idea**

The native controls such as `alert()` or `confirm()`, `prompt()` etc doesn't provide more than two options.

Is there a native control , that can provide more than two options..?

If not, How can I create one using angular-ui or jquery-ui?

Comment: If the options are mutually-exclusive, use an `<input type="radio" />`, or a `<select>` (with the relevant options); if more than one of the alternatives can be selected, then use `<input type="checkbox" />`, or a `<select multiple="multiple">` element (again: with the relevant options). Incidentally, this would seem more a [UI.SE] question, than programming (but do read their [guidance](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first); as such I'm afraid I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user-interface alternatives, rather than 'programming.'

Comment: @DavidThomas, Am sorry, I should have posted this question in UX site.

Comment: No problem, I'd suggest either self-deleting (there should be a usable 'delete' link below your question) or voting to close (that way, hopefully, you won't attract any down-votes).

Comment: @DavidThomas, But stackOverFlow is not recomending me to delete the question since it has answer. and i'm not able to see any option like 'close'

Comment: If I were you I'd use two checkboxes: `Idea` which when ticked enables `Yes/No`. It's all too easy to devolve three-state values into [something like this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="no"> No<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="no_idea" checked> No Idea<br>
```

It's just standard html. Why you think it's need jquery or angular ?

Comment: Please, at least take the time to associate the text with the relevant input: `<label><input name="options" value="yes" />yes</label>` (this is a UI-led question, after all; even if it's on the wrong site).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI [`dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widgets [`buttons`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) option.

It accepts either an object whose keys are the buttons's label, and value is the callback function or an array of objects defining the attributes, properties, and event handlers to set on the button.

The context of the callback functions is the dialog element. You can use the `target` property of event in case you want to access the button.

---

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title:"Is it suitable?",
    buttons: [{
      text: "Yes",
      click: function(event) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "No",
      click: function(event) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "No Idea",
      click: function(event) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```